should v-model:rail and :rail behave differently in a vuetify v-navigation-drawer?
I have a vuetify v-navigation-drawer component and I'd like to give the user the option to pin it open or let it be a rail.  Reading through the docs, I thought v-model:rail was the way to go, but in practice :rail gives me what I want.  I also thought that those were the same things.
If I change v-model:rail="isRail" to just :rail=isRail then I get the behavior I expect when clicking my toggle button.  The reason appears to be that when you hover over a rail it actually stops being a rail entirely, so hovering over v-model:rail immediately sets the variable to false. But if you just use :rail, then it expands to rail="true" or rail="false" as appropriate and you can easily make it be isRail=!isRail and the content in the v-main is displayed correctly.
Is this the intended behavior?
The vuetify playground is giving me fits this morning, but here is the code.  Just pasted it in and change v-model:rail="isRail" to :rail="isRail" to see the difference.
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { type Ref, ref } from 'vue';

  const isRail: Ref<boolean> = ref(true);
</script>
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-layout>
      <v-navigation-drawer expand-on-hover v-model:rail="isRail">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            prepend-avatar="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/85.jpg"
            subtitle="sandra_a88@gmailcom"
            title="Sandra Adams"
          ></v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list density="compact" nav>
          <v-list-item
            prepend-icon="mdi-chevron-double-right"
            role="button"
            @click="isRail = !isRail"
          >
            Pin Open
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item
            prepend-icon="mdi-folder"
            title="My Files"
            value="myfiles"
          ></v-list-item>
          <v-list-item
            prepend-icon="mdi-account-multiple"
            title="Shared with me"
            value="shared"
          ></v-list-item>
          <v-list-item
            prepend-icon="mdi-star"
            title="Starred"
            value="starred"
          ></v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>

      <v-main style="height: 250px">
        <p>
          the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox
          jumped over the lazy dog.
        </p>
        <p style="padding-left: 300px">isRail is: {{isRail}}</p>
      </v-main>
    </v-layout>
  </v-card>
</template>


There's a difference between v-model and props.  According to the Vuetify API, rails is a prop, and is not designed to be used as a v-model.  It makes sense then that using it as a prop gives the correct functionality.

Interesting.  The docs say To have content area respond to expand-on-hover, bind v-model:rail to a data prop. and since I wanted to have my content area respond to the hover, that's what I did.  But using @update:rail="(event) => { myFunction(event); }" to respond to expand-on-hover combined with :rail="myRailVariable let me do what I wanted.  I'm assuming that when the docs say a data prop they do not mean a component property, just a variable declared as Ref type.

They do mention v-model in the actual component page, but don't list it on the API page, so now I don't actually know how it can be used... This tracks with my opinion that the Vuetify 3 docs are not always totally accurate, or sometimes is missing information. Sometimes it's best to open an issue on their github or ask a question on their discord server to get to the bottom of something.
